# UnicodeEncodeError in xarray .to_netcdf

Tags: netcdf, python-xarray

I encountered an error when saving the revised netcdf file on the Linux server. The code is

```
cygnss_ds.to_netcdf(cygnss_path.replace('raw_data', 'annotated_data'))
```

The error is

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode characters in position 5295-5297: surrogates not allowed
```

I found a similar problem in the Xarray GitHub issue, they said the reason for this problem is <"a byte object contains plain text character (éàè.. ) (like NetCDF metadata can be), breaking the utf8 encoding and decoding."> Besides, they said, <"This can be corrected with the following Error Handler: errors=surrogateescape". >

However, I didn't find the plain text in my data and am unclear on how to use this error handler. There seems to be no argument about "errors" in the .to_netcdf function.